# Comparing 2 Files by Size Using Variable in the Path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare 2 files using their size, but i need to use get-date as variable in the path:

```
$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$culture = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Clone()
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
$currentdate = get-date -format "yyyyMM"

$FileSize1 = (Get-Item 'C:\FolderA\$currentdate.rar')

$FileSize2 = (Get-Item 'C:\FolderB\$currentdate.rar')


if($FileSize1.Length -eq $FileSize2.Length) {
 Write-Host EQUAL
} Else {
  Write-Host DIFERENT



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$culture = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Clone()
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
$currentdate = get-date -format "yyyyMM"

$FileSize1 = Get-Item "C:\FolderA\$($currentdate).rar"

$FileSize2 = Get-Item "C:\FolderB\$($currentdate).rar"


if($FileSize1.Length -eq $FileSize2.Length) {
 Write-Host EQUAL
} Else {
  Write-Host DIFERENT



}
```

You need use the sub -expression  operator $() in the get-item to concatenate variable and strings.